# Why is the source code 'all red' in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, sdk

I'm always using Android Studio's debugger to walk through the code and see how things work.

As I dive deeper into the SDK, I get to lisView.java for example, and now it's class members are mostly red? (see link)

Why is that?? I could see my code and parts of the SDK prior to 'stepping in' listView.java?  Why suddenly is it all red on the right-had column?

As you see in the screenshot, now I can't see the value for
the member variable, mOldItemCount for example.
[image: screen shot of listView.java]

Comment: Nope. I'm thinking it has to do with 'access' to the actual Android source code.

Answer (score 22):

Try file -> invalidate caches / restart -> Invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 6):

Sync Gradle and Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting .gradle and .idea folder of project. For me its solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Fixes:

1. Sync Gradle
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Clean and Rebuild

A Possible other problem that can occur is that you moved the location of the file. Its happened to me before.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing `.idea` or at least files inside of it, even if while you're opening `Android Studio` a popup alert will be shown to tell you to reload your project and it everything will go back normally

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `.gradle`, `.idea` and `build` folders of the project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a red code like the image is because the autogenerate files and de gradle its not working well.

I try this options in order:

First,  Check de import and be sure are the rigth imports

Second, Sync Gradle and Rebuild Project.

Third, Clean project

If the problem persist try checking the android dependencies and see which one is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Methods named (A) (B) (C) (D), do not help you, then the following 4 steps are AGNI ASTRA.

Step 1 : Go To App Folder In Android Studio.

Step 2 : Locate Build Folder.

Step 3 : Delete Build Folder.

Step 4 : Sync File.

I will advise to use AGNI ASTRA, after trying, Methods named (A) (B) (C) (D) .

The Methods Are :

Method (A)

- CLICK ON FILE IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON SYNC PROJECT WITH GRADLE FILES

Method (B)

- CLICK ON FILE IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON INVALIDATE CACHES

Method (C)

- CLICK ON BUILD IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON CLEAN PROJECT

Method (D)

- CLICK ON BUILD IN ANDROID STUDIO
- CLICK ON REBUILD PROJECT

Comment: question is referencing files inside android SDK